# "Improper data type" with query in Rocket UNIVERSE database

Tags: universe

I am trying to do a simple LIST from the UV command line:

```
LIST PSUB TSN.COMMENT
```

I get the following:

```
LIST PSUB TSN.COMMENT 07:37:39am  22 Mar 2014  PAGE    1
@ID..................................... TSN..........

**Program "DICT.GET.LEDGER.DET.VALUE": Line 9, Improper data type.**
```

Looking further, I can see the following details on the field:

```
TSN.COMMENT
TYPE: I
LOC: SUBR('DICT.GET.LEDGER.DET.VALUE',FIELD(@ID,'~',4),FIELD(@ID,'~',6),FIELD(@ID,' ',5)"R%3",'3')<1,1,2>
CONV:
NAME: TSN
FORMAT: 13L
SM: S
```

The application we are using against this database is EPICOR Ecplise -- Reports generated from the tools they provide that include this field do work, so I don't think there is a problem with the data file -- I think it is just me; I'm not that familiar with this type of database and don't know what I don't know.

The DICT.GET.LEDGER.DET.VALUE Program is as follows:

> ED OC DICT.GET.LEDGER.VALUE
>   531 lines long.

```
----: P
0001:           SUBROUTINE (VAL,ATTB)
0002:           $INCLUDE AD.DIR CC~COMMON
0003: *
0004: *
<--And lots more after that -->
```

I think the code is OK because there are lots of other I type fields that use similar SUBR's that error out in the same way when called directory from UV.  I think I'm just missing something.

And then looking at what is in CC~COMMON:

```
          COMMON /STDCOM/ COMDATA(150),SECURITY,MAIN.MEN,FILES(50),AOFILES(150),GLDATA(35)
** Version# 13 - 05/07/2008 - 10:24am - BABS - main

          COMMON FLAGS(100)
          COMMON TCL.LEVEL., RECALL.FLAG, E.MESS.
          COMMON LED(200),OLED(200),LD(150),OLD.LD(150)
          COMMON PRD(200),PRDP(30),PRD.BR(70),PRDC.BR(30),PRDD.BR(40)
          COMMON PGRP(10),PLNE(30),PLNE.BR(20),PLNB(5),BL.BR(50)
          COMMON CUS(200),CUSS(200),MA(40)
          COMMON TAX(20),AR(50)
          COMMON SCROLL.VAR, SVIEW.DEF., SVIEW.DATA.(10)

          $INCLUDE CC EQU.ESC.OBJECT
          $INCLUDE CC EQUATES

          PROMPT CHAR(0)
!BABS~05/07/08~10:24
* Compiled by ECLIPSE on 02/11/12 09:29 from CC:COMMON
*** Version# 13 - 05/07/2008 - 10:24am - BABS - main
```

Comment: What is the code of the subroutine DICT.GET.LEDGER.DET.VALUE? You can open the program by entering at the command line "ED <program file> DICT.GET.LEDGER.DET.VALUE". Normally the program file is BP. Therefore, your command would be "ED BP DICT.GET.LEDGER.DET.VALUE". If that doesn't work, you can look up the program file by looking at line 2 of the VOC entry for the program "ED VOC DICT.GET.LEDGER.DET.VALUE"

Comment: Also, do you still get the error if you limit your LIST selection to only one record:
LIST SAMPLE 1 TSN.COMMENT PSUB

Comment: Thanks for the input!  Yes, just doing a sample of 1 yields the same error.  I have posted the code for the program file above.  Thanks for the command to find it.

Comment: Now that I have placed the code for the subroutine into the question, does that shed any light as to the problem?

Comment: Looking at this code, LEDFILE on line 9 has not been opened.  I don't see an argument variable, OPEN statement, or COMMON block that has this file already opened.  It is highly likely this is one of your issue.

Comment: Looking further it occurred to me that maybe I am looking in the wrong place.  The DICT.GET.LEDGER.DET.VALUE subroutine is in BP, but when I check in the VOC (ED VOC DICT.GET.LEDGER.DET.VALUE) it is pointing to the same subroutine in a different place.  line 002: OC.O/DICT.GET.LEDGE/R.DET.VALUE.  And this subroutine is slightly different.  Also, I don't see a LEDFILE anywhere -- is this a logical reference to a file with a different name?  The thing is, this works when invoked from the report writer program.  I'm missing something somewhere.

Comment: This is now probably too specific for the SO community, but looking into this further I am sure this is an environment issue; I just don't know where to look.  The system that "talks" to this database is called "Eclipse" and is a terminal based menu driven system that pops up when one logs in via a TERMINAL session.  When using this menu I can drop down to a TCL command prompt and issue the same command > LIST PSUB TSN.COMMENT and it works!  So how do I figure out what is being set so I don't have to use the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a wrapper routine to call OPEN.STANDARD.FILES:

```
>ED BP OPEN.STANDARD.FILES.TCL
001 * OPEN.STANDARD.FILES.TCL
002 CALL OPEN.STNADARD.FILES
003 STOP
004 END

>BASIC BP OPEN.STANDARD.FILES.TCL
>CATALOG BP OPEN.STANDARD.FILES.TCL
```

Then you can execute OPEN.STANDARD.FILES.TCL before your list statement.  This is important if you are not starting Epicor's framework, like when you want to access this data with .NET or ODBC.

-Nathan